# Como utilizar Gearman con PHP en Windows

Tags: php, windows, procesos-en-segundo-plano

intento utilizar [Gearman](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.gearman.php) para ejecutar procesos es segundo plano, el cual descargo de la pagina  [Download](http://gearman.org/download/) pero al tratar de implementala no me funciona, intento con los comando

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

desde consola como se explica en [Primeros pasos con Gearman](http://engineering.emagister.com/2011/10/27/tutorial-gearman/) sigo todos los pasos pero me quedo en esos tres comando ya que `./configure` no lo reconoce ya instale GunWin32 para instalas las dependencias y los comandos `make make install` ya los reconoce pero no hacen nada ya que el comando .configure no lo acepta

Comment: descomprimiste el tar? y diste un cd a la carpeta que se creo al descomprimir el archivo?

Comment: si descomprimí me cambie a la carpeta y ahí trate de ejecutar los comandos  y nada el `./configure` me marca `"." no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.`

Comment: que tipo de linux estas utilizando???

Comment: estoy utilizando `windows`,  se que los `comandos` son de `linux` pero a lo que vi en el `manual` que esta en el `enlace` debería funcionar con windows instalando las dependencias que están en `GunWin32`

Comment: verificaste que el `ruta` de `gunwin32` se alla agregado al path de windows?? y de paso instalase `libevent`

Comment: si en la variable phat esta agregado como `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` junto con otras rutas

Comment: intenta mejor con [cywin](http://www.cygwin.com/) es mucho mejor que `gunwim32` y de paso luego de esto reboot es `windows`

Comment: y que dependencias o que debo instalar ahí ???????????????